# Change css of master page element using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I want to highlight main menu when i am on any of the sublink page.

For that I am trying to apply css to main menu link in master page from content page.

code for menu is like:

```
 <div class="menu">
                 <ul id="vertical-navigation">
                    <li runat="server" id="liConfiguration" class="main_link"><a href="#">Configuration</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="">
                                <div class="ParentMenu">
                                    <div class="ChildItem">
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/xyz/xyz.aspx">xyz Master</asp:HyperLink></div>
                                    <iframe src="" class="IframeMenuItem" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

So in this case when i go to xyz.aspx i want to change css of 'liConfiguration' to "active_butn"

I want to write jquery function for changing css...how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you asked for a jquery code (and there are 2 answers for that), I think that a server code might be better here. It would be safer when you might want to change the element id.

In master:

```
public void ChangeConfigurationElementClass(string className)
{
    liConfiguration.Attributes["class"] = className;
}
```

In page:

```
var master = Master as MyMaster;

if (master != null)
    master.ChangeConfigurationElementClass("active_butn");
```

Comment: I did this...with one change. Instead of writing code in master page i wrote it in PageBase..and it worked too..

Answer (score 0):

```
var $path = window.location.pathname;

var $indexPath = function ($path) {

            if ($path.indexOf('xyz') > -1) {
                $('#liConfiguration').addClass("active_butn");
            }
            else {
                $('#liConfiguration').addClass("main_link");
            }
}
```

i hope this would be fine to add new class
$indexPath($path);

Comment: You don't need to check the page url. You can just put this script only in the xyz page.

Comment: yea its another option but if u put in master page u must better to solve problem